# Firebase Merge providers when logging in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm trying to create a login system where when you sign in, it checks for your email if there is a different provider signed in using that email and automatically merge it.

Normally, when signing in using email and password, then sign in using Google, it will override the email provider. And if I try signing in using a different provider using the same email, it will throw an error saying there is already a user using the email.

So, I changed the authentication to allow multiple account per email address so that when a new account is created it will be seperated to an existing one, then I can programatically merge those 2 accounts together using the email. The problem now is that when it's signed in, the email will be `null` which means I cannot identify if there is an account using the same email address.

I want to be able to wirte a code that automatically merge auth providers when signing in using different providers and the email address is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic merging of accounts.  You have to write code to link them, as you've already discovered.

Comment: I already know that, I want to know how exactly can I do this?

Comment: Your question suggested that "I can programatically merge those 2 accounts together using the email".  It would be the same procedure, as described in the documentation for linking accounts. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

Comment: If you are having a specific problem with the code to link the accounts, then you should edit your question to be clear about what that is, showing the code that doesn't work the way you expect.